# validating phone number in Javascript with hyphens

Tags: javascript

ok So I've tried to validate a phone number script for the past 2 hours but I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. the Maximum length is 12 and I've already got an if statement for that, that works.

the format would have to be :   nnn-nnn-nnnn

```
         var tele = document.pizza.field03;  //store phone number
         var fone = tele.value               //store values of variable tele in fone
         var acode = "";                    
         var midnum = "";                    
         var lasnum = "";                    
         var hyphen = "";                  
         var hyphen2 ="";                        

   acode=fone.substr(0,3);
   hyphen=fone.substr(3,4);
   midnum=fone.substr(4,7);
   hyphen2=fone.substr(7,8);
   lasnum=fone.substr(8);

       else if (isNaN(acode) )
         {
           errMessages += "<li>Please use integer numbers only</li>\n";
           errMessages += "<li>ex: 1 2 3 4 5 </li>\n";
         }

       else if (isNaN(midnum) )
         {
           errMessages += "<li>Please use integer numbers only</li>\n";
           errMessages += "<li>ex: 1 2 3 4 5 </li>\n";
         }

       else if (isNaN(lasnum) )
         {
           errMessages += "<li>Please use integer numbers only</li>\n";
           errMessages += "<li>ex: 1 2 3 4 5 </li>\n";
         }
```

***EDIT****

```
else if (hyphen.indexOf('-') ==-1)                  //checking for hyphen
     {
       errMessages += "<li>You need a hyphen after the area code</li>\n"
       errMessages += "<li>ex: areacode-nnn-nnn</li>\n"
     }

   else if (hyphen2.indexOf('-') ==-1)
     {
       errMessages += "<li>You need a hyphen after the middle 3 digits</li>\n";
       errMessages += "<li>ex: 416-mid-1234</li>\n";
     }
```

what happens is whether I use digits or letters it'll keep popping up the error window.

I want to learn how to do this without using RegEx if possible.
Thank you.

Comment: Bear in mind a lot of users have no idea what an "integer" is; consider using friendlier language. Also ew; not only is the code duplicated, but you could get three identical messages for a single field.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah I just threw something in there and LOL @ the ew part...yeah as for the duplicated code I didn't know how to put that all in one.

Comment: Why do you not want to use regex? You can validate the whole thing in one line with regex, and replace all of your error messages with a single "Phone number must be in the format nnn-nnn-nnnn" message...

Comment: @nnnnnn it's an odd reason I know, but I just wanted to learn how to code in Javascript without RegEx. I understand Regex would have been easier quicker and probably more efficient but this method helps me learn in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
acode=fone.substr(0,3);
hyphen=fone.substr(3,4);
midnum=fone.substr(4,7);
hyphen2=fone.substr(7,8);
lasnum=fone.substr(8);
```

The second parameter specifies the *length* of the string taken, not the "end position". ([See reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp))

Your variables come out with the values 'nnn', '-nnn', 'nnn-nnnn', '-nnnn' and 'nnnn'.

```
acode=fone.substr(0,3);
hyphen=fone.substr(3,1);
midnum=fone.substr(4,3);
hyphen2=fone.substr(7,1);
lasnum=fone.substr(8);
```

Comment: ! thank you that was my problem. so the following number after the comma is the length of the string okay, I understand that. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `substr` is `string.substr(start,length)`.

You, however, seem to be calling it with `string.substr(start,end)`.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) for more details